# Updating parent component state from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one parent component that holds state of clicking : if file is clicked or not.

Files come from child component.

I know that I can use props and call function from parent, but doing that, I get this.props.handleStateChange is not a function

```
    export class Parent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clickable: false
        };

        this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this);
        }

        handleStateChange = (val) => {
            this.setState({ clickable: val })
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Child handleStateChange={this.handleStateChange} />
            );
        }
    }

    class Child extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
            clickable: false
            };
        }

        handleClick = () => {
            this.state.clickable ? this.setState({ clickable: false }) : 
            this.setState({ clickable: true });

            this.props.handleStateChange(this.state.clickable)
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className={this.state.clickable ? 'clickable' : null} 
                >
                    <img className="item" src={file} alt="file" onClick= 
                {this.handleClick} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Any ideas what am I missing there?

Comment: `this.props..... is not a function` What function is in `...` ?

Comment: Sorry, edited question.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you are getting, the code in your question works fine with no errors

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-meninsky-dr67s) everything is working fine, no errors.

If the code you add in your question isn't the real code you are working with, maybe try checking for typos.

Probably you are passing the prop with the wrong/different name.

## Some tips that aren't related to the question

Instead of

```
this.state.clickable
  ? this.setState({ clickable: false })
  : this.setState({ clickable: true });
```

You should do

```
this.setState(prevState => ({clickable: !prevState.clickable}))
```

Comment: I just changed components names. But indeed, your example works. Gonna double check everything although have done it couple of times, frustrated already :/

Comment: @Pleats maybe the error is from another component? Have you checked for typos?

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, so using your newly set state immediately after isn't guaranteed to work.  Instead, try this for handleClick:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        this.props.handleStateChange({ !prevState.clickable });
        return { clickable: !prevState.clickable };
    })
}
```

That said, you're maintaining the same state in the parent and child.  Probably better to set it in the parent (from the child) and pass it to the child as a prop.

Also also, since you're using an arrow function, you don't need to `bind` any of your functions in the constructor.

Comment: Can't use this. I think it don't like '!' as it says: non-null assertions can only be used in a -ts file. Property assignment expected.